# Find multiple index in array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Say I have an array like this

```
  string [] fruits = {"watermelon","apple","apple","kiwi","pear","banana"};
```

Is there an built in function that allows me to query all the index of "apple" ?
For example,

```
  fruits.FindAllIndex("apple");
```

will return an array of 1 and 2

If there is not, how should I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to write like this:

```
var indices = fruits
                .Select ((f, i) => new {f, i})
                .Where (x => x.f == "apple")
                .Select (x => x.i);
```

Or the traditional way:

```
var indices = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.Length; i++)
    if(fruits[i] == "apple")
        indices.Add(i);
```

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz And that's bad - why?

Comment: I don't think he's saying that's bad, just providing additional information.

Comment: @Magnus it works great! thanks! But I don't understand how the first SELECT knows 'f' is the content of the object and 'i' is the index? Thanks!

Comment: @Fever it is using [this select function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) where the selector has both the object and the index.

Answer (score 12):

LINQ version:

```
var indexes = fruits.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                    .Where(x => x.value == "apple")
                    .Select(x => x.index)
                    .ToList();
```

Non-LINQ version, using `Array<T>.IndexOf()` static method:

```
var indexes = new List<int>();
var lastIndex = 0;

while ((lastIndex = Array.IndexOf(fruits, "apple", lastIndex)) != -1)
{
    indexes.Add(lastIndex);
    lastIndex++;
}
```

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz Sorry I'm very new at Linq, could you explain what do you mean by lazy? Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the `.ToList()` in the first method, your function will be lazy. This means if you ran `indexes.Take(2)`, the function can stop executing once two indexes have been found, rather than finding ALL indexes first, then removing all but the first two.

Comment: ToList doesn't make it finding all indexes first, he still stop when the first two item are found... ToList just make the query run now instead of being deferred

Comment: @FabioMarcolini how to be case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with an extension method.

```cs
var fruits = new[] { "watermelon","apple","apple","kiwi","pear","banana" };
var indexes = fruits.FindAllIndexes("apple");

public static class Extensions
{
  public static int[] FindAllIndexes(this string[] array, string search) => array
      .Select((x, i) => (x, i))
      .Where(value => value.x == search)
      .Select(value => value.i)
      .ToArray();
}
```